# Is there a bundle/plugin/etc for TextMate to enable function declaration search across files?

Tags: macos, textmate

Many modern IDEs provide the ability to jump to the function declaration by using a simple shortcut or special mouse click on a function call.  This is the one thing that stops TextMate from being my one IDE to rule them all.

So far I find TextMate great for web development and scripting, but doing large scale C++ or Java development on it can feel a little handicapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20100730045253/http://vision-media.ca:80/resources/php/textmate-jump-to-function-declaration) how to do it in TextMate (from [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GvfrNIkq7mUJ:vision-media.ca.sharedcopy.com/resources/php/611c23e67eda59611a712640f0ef7719.html%20http://vision-media.ca/resources/php/textmate-jump-to-function-declaration&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)):

> Many IDEs have the capability to 'jump' to a function declaration
> within the project you are working in. This is how to do it in
> TextMate. Assuming you understand bundles the Bash script below should
> be placed in a Command with output set to Show As Tool Tip, then
> finally picking the key combination you want.
>
> Once ready simply press the key combination while the Caret is placed
> over your function. The script below will iterate through PHP related
> files look for the declaration, then opening a TextMate document at
> the proper line. When this script fails a tooltip mention so will be
> displayed.
>
> ```
> FUNC="$TM_CURRENT_WORD"
> DIR="$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
> OUTPUT=''
>
> FILES=(`find "$DIR" -type f | egrep '\.(module|inc|php|engine|install)$'`)
>
> #
> # Look for a function declaration within a files contents.
> #
> # <file> <function>
> #
> function lookup_function {
>   local line=`nl -b a "$1" | grep 'function '"$2"'(' | awk '{print $1}'`
>   if [[ "$line" -gt 0 ]]; then
>     mate "$1" -l "$line"
>     exit 0
>   fi
> }
>
> # Iterate files
> for (( i=0; i < ${#FILES[*]}; i++)); do
>   file="${FILES[${i}]}"
>   lookup_function "$file" "$FUNC"
> done
>
> # Nothing found
> echo 'Function '${FUNC}' was not found within the current project.'
> ```

Also, check this out: https://web.archive.org/web/20210408114313/http://www.cocoabits.com/TmCodeBrowser/

Answer (score 1):

I modified ghoppe's script to work for Python class & function definitions (also runs a little faster):

```
FUNC="$TM_CURRENT_WORD"
DIR="$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
OUTPUT=''

# Define the class or function definition string that we're looking for.
FUNCDEF='(def|class) '$FUNC

# Find all files that contain FUNCDEF
FILES=(`egrep "$FUNCDEF" $DIR/* -r -l --include=*.py`)

#
# Look for a function declaration within a files contents.
#
# <file>
#
function lookup_function {
    local line=`nl -b a "$1" | egrep "$FUNCDEF" | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [[ "$line" -gt 0 ]]; then
      # echo 'Jumping to --> '$1':'$line
      mate "$1" -l "$line"
      exit 0
    fi
}

# Iterate files
for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
    echo $file
    lookup_function "$file"
done

# Nothing found
echo 'Function '${FUNC}' was not found within the current project.'
```

Answer (score 0):

While TextMate has lexical formatting (bolding, italics, coloring, etc.) it doesn't have a true grasp of the actual code which you are typing in it.  In order to do more complicated things like you are wanting, TextMate would need to do another type of analysis in addition to the formatting which is getting closer to a compiler.
From what I know TextMate doesn't support this functionality right now.